# Insert a link, Search tab, giving wrong ID of the item and link is broken

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, content-editor

I am using Sitecore 7, in rich text editor I want to add a link to a pdf file, I used "Add a Link" option from the tool bar, I went to "search" tab which I believe is new in this version of Sitecore, I searched my item and inserted a link, Sitecore uses following format for insert the link

> a
>   href="~/link.aspx?_id=C3D29351D91C48E1A42C15E64060C547&_z=z

But the ID generated by the search function is not correct, it does not exist in the Sitecore database, If I manually edit the ID to the valid ID, it works, Why search function gives me a wrong ID?
See attched image as well.[image]

Comment: It could be that the index has an old version. Have you added, removed and re-added stuff to the media library? In any case it couldnt hurt to re-index the master index via sitecore shell > control panel > Indexing > indexing manager > select 'sitecore_master_index' and click rebuild.

Comment: I have rebuild all web, master and core indexes but same problem, I tried to link any other document but having same issue.

Comment: I recommend you open the master index in luke and locate the record with that given id. It should give you more info about what was indexed, could you share that when you have found it?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a ticket to the support yesterday about that issue, i'll edit my answer when i get an answer back (They can reproduce the error on a clean 7.2)

I've make a blog post which talk about the issue and give the ticket number (you can as the patch to the support)

http://sitecorefun.baziret.com/?p=131

Comment: As an addition to the mentioned hotfix from Sitecore, this should be fixed in Sitecore 7.2 rev. 141226 (7.2 Service Pack-1, originally released as 7.2 Update-3).